# Subworkflow as an implicit dependency

Tags: snakemake

I've designed a subworkflow that works well if it is specified as an explicit input in the rule `all`:

```
rule all:
    input: anotherworkflow("data/a.txt")
```

Now I need to inject this subworkflow as an intermediate rule of my workflow: I need to employ the subworkflow if any other rule needs the file `data/a.txt`. The subworkflow can be specified only in the `input` part of the rule, so I design a "bridge" rule:

```
rule all:
    input: ".work/data/a.txt"

subworkflow anotherworkflow:
    workdir: ".work"
    snakefile: "another.Snakefile"

rule bridge:
    input: anotherworkflow("data/a.txt")
    output: ".work/data/a.txt"
```

I expect that the `bridge` rule declares as an output the same file that the subworkflow produces, and that would allow me to run the subworkflow whenever any rule needs the file. But that doesn't work. The exception is `MissingOutputException`, "Missing files after 5 seconds".

Am I doing something wrong? Should this approach work? Does this work on any other OS (I'm using Windows + MinGW)?

Comment: In your example code, `input` and `output` filenames for rule `bridge` are the same (`.work/data/a.txt`) when resolved. Ideally it should have resulted in `CyclicGraphException` but it doesn't seem to when using `subworkflow`. Try changing `output` filename. Also, showing code in `another.Snakefile` would help.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy The another.Snakemake is irrelevant: that is just something that creates the file (i.e. `touch data/a.txt`). I would agree that there is a logic behind the idea of throwing the `CyclicGraphException` but as long as the rule cannot contain the subworkflow in the `output` section, there should be another way to say: "If any rule needs the file "data/a.txt", take it as a result of running the subworkflow". I thought my code says exactly that.

Comment: I tried similar code using snakemake `v5.4.0` and macOS Sierra, and it worked well as you expected.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy Thank you, looks like that is  the problem of my unusual environment again.